# Make onclick only affect the element, not it's children as well

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am making a personal website. I want to make it so that cliking the background changes the theme from dark to light and vice/versa. It works, but I dont want it to switch the theme if the user clicks on text, only the background of the webpage For example, if I click the text at the bottom it changes the css, but it should only do that if you click the white background.
Here is [my code](http://github.com/FirstWorldAnarchy/firstworldanarchy.github.io) (Mainly checkout js/main.js, the switchTheme function and the index.html) and the [website](http://firstworldanarchy.github.io) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$("#container").on("click", "div", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  switchTheme();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a test to see if the ID of the clicked element was actually the container.

```
function switchTheme( event ) {

  if ( event.target.id === 'container' ) { //the container was clicked, and not a text node

      if (dark) {
        $("#container").css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255,0.7);");
        $("#container").css("color", "black");
        dark = false;
      } else {
        $("#container").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.7);");
        $("#container").css("color", "white");
        dark = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting your container class.  Anytime that div (or anything in it) gets clicked, that event will fire.  Try stopping the event propagation on your click event if $('this').selector === 'p' or whatever class you're using.

Also - not bad for 13 boss!

```
$( document ).click(function( event ) {
  //  if statement here
    event.stopPropagation();
  // else the regular behavior
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help! I'd almost given up and wanted to use a button to toggle it instead. The more you know!
And since this is an answer to my question: e.stopPropogation()

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log("Heeeeyyy! Hoooo!"))
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; background-color: lightcoral;  width: 500px; height: 180px;">
</div>

<div style="position: fixed; background-color: lightblue; width: 300px; height: 100px;">
  <p>You can not click through me!</p>
</div>
```

- Don't put the elements inside the "parent".
- Move them together only by style.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following:

```
$("#container").on("click", "div", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```